# Agglomerative hierarchical clustering technique

Tags: machine-learning, cluster-analysis, data-mining, hierarchical-clustering

Earlier in the year, my AI lecturer taught us about agglomerative hierarchical clustering and K means clustering but his explanations are lost and i'm trying to figure out how he uses the data in the table below to create a dendogram. It would be great.

[image]

He comes up with the following table that outlines the similarities:

```
   Animal pairs          Similarities
Bear & Tiger                  4
Bear & Dog                    3
Bear & Giant Squid            2
Bear & Cat                    3
Tiger & Dog                   2
Tiger & Giant Squid           1
Tiger & Cat                   2
Dog & Giant Squid             2
Dog & Cat                     5
Giant Squid & Cat             2
```

And the resulting dendogram from the table above:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always connect the most similar ones.

Dog and Cat are most similar, and are thus connected at level 5.

Bear and Tiger are connected at level 4.

etc.

Comment: In addition to the answer, an article that explains an algorithm to build a [Hierarchical agglomerative clustering](http://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/html/htmledition/hierarchical-agglomerative-clustering-1.html)